Excel Sum Complication
I enter numbers into row 4 at various parts during the night shift.  However, the numbers will not always be put in the same hour every night.  A number will be entered at least once every 4 hours.
At the moment I have to manually calculate the value in row 5.  I have looked at various "if" statements and formula logic but without success.
In summary I would like the value in row 8 to add up to the latest value hour entered into row 4.  I.e.  1,000 was entered into "D4" and this makes "C8" and "D8" 500 each as it is 1,000 divided 2.
I hope this makes sense?  Any support on a solution is appreciated.
Many thanks, Alan.


The formula in cell C8 is and drag right
=LET(rval,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(C4:$K$4),C4:$K$4,MAX(C4:K4)+1)),
lval,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER($C$4:C4),$C$4:C4,0)),
lpos,MATCH(lval,$C$4:$K$4,0),
rpos,MATCH(rval,$C$4:$K$4,0),
empty,rpos-IFERROR(lpos,0),
percell,(rval-lval)/empty,
IFERROR(percell,OFFSET(C8,0,-1)))


IMROVED
The following formula counts with the possibilities that the first cell contains a value, two adjacent cells contains values, same values occur in cells, the end of the range not contains a value.
=LET(leftval,MAX($B$4:B4),
rightval,MIN(C4:$K$4),
left,COLUMN(XLOOKUP(leftval,$B$4:B4,$B$4:B4,$B$4,0,-1)),
right,COLUMN(XLOOKUP(rightval,C4:$K$4,C4:$K$4,$K$4,0)),
val,(rightval-leftval)/(right-left),
IF(val<0,0,val))



Hello there,  I have noticed one issue with the above.  Lets say the 6,000 wasnt there in the example above it would leave the 833.33 for all future hours.  Happy to add a new question if thats best way to do this?

I don't know which is the best.. I already met with both workarounds. I now add the improved formula with the more detailed specs.

Improved section looks promising.  Just woke up so will do some testing this morning.  Thank you.

=LET(r,C4:K4,
     a,MAP(r,LAMBDA(m,@IFERROR(TOCOL(m:K4,1),0))),
     b,MAP(r,LAMBDA(m,MAX(IFERROR(TOCOL(DROP(C4:m,,-1),1),0)))),
(a-b>0)*(a-b)/BYCOL(a,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(a=x)))))

